# How do I get a Html from a WidgetT site m ()?

Tags: haskell, yesod

I'm building up a `Mail` with `import Network.Mail.Mime.SES`, and the HTML part of my email needs a `Html` value.

I can get an `Html` like this:

```
import Text.Blaze.Html.Renderer.Utf8 (renderHtml)

emailHtml :: Html
emailHtml = renderHtml $(shamletFile "templates/email.hamlet")
```

However, the template I'm using should have a reference to a static file. I want to reference it with `@{StaticR img_myimage_jpg}`, but using URLs like this does not work with *shamlet*. Instead, I think I need to use *whamlet*, but if I use `whamletFile` with `renderHtml`, I get a compiler error.

Using `whamletFile` produces this compiler error:

```
Handler/Proxy.hs:71:55:
    Couldn't match expected type `blaze-markup-0.7.1.0:Text.Blaze.Internal.MarkupM
                                    ()'
                with actual type `WidgetT site12 m12 ()'
    In a stmt of a 'do' block:
      (asWidgetT GHC.Base.. toWidget)
        ((blaze-markup-0.7.1.0:Text.Blaze.Internal.preEscapedText
          GHC.Base.. Data.Text.pack)
           "</pre>\n\
           \</td>\n\
           \</tr>\n\
           \</table>\n\
           \</td>\n\
           \</tr>\n\
           ... (many more lines)
```

Using `hamletFile` produces this compiler error:

```
Handler/Proxy.hs:71:53:
    Couldn't match expected type `t0
                                  -> blaze-markup-0.7.1.0:Text.Blaze.Internal.MarkupM ()'
                with actual type `blaze-markup-0.7.1.0:Text.Blaze.Internal.MarkupM
                                    ()'
    The lambda expression `\ _render_aoYP -> ...' has one argument,
    but its type `Html' has none
    In the first argument of `renderHtml', namely
      `\ _render_aoYP
         -> do { GHC.Base.id
                   ((blaze-markup-0.7.1.0:Text.Blaze.Internal.preEscapedText
                     GHC.Base.. Data.Text.pack)
                      "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd\">\n\
```

Comment: It would be useful to know which compiler error you get using `whamletFile`.

Comment: Why not hamletFile? You won't want most of the functionality of a widget, like CSS and JavaScript.

Comment: @gigabytes Sure; I updated my question.

Comment: @MichaelSnoyman Different compiler error, though just as cryptic to me currently. I'm not sure what a `t0` is.

Comment: You need to provide it with a URL rendering function. You can get it with getUrlRenderParams